# Algebraic varieties and coverings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$  ad $Y$ are algebraic varieties over an algebraic closed field, what does exactly mean that $Y$ is a covering of $X$? Is $Y$ only a topological covering of $X$?

I will appreciate a reference.

**Addenda in response to the above comments:** Consider for example the following definition from the article "F.Catanese - Fibered Surfaces, Varieties Isogenous to a Product and Related Moduli Spaces":

> $\quad$ *Definition $3.1$.* A surface $S$ is said to be *isogenous to a product* if $S$ admits a finite unramified covering which is isomorphic to a product of curves ($u:C_1\times C_2\to S$) of genera $g_i=\text{genus}(C_i)\ge1$. In the case where each $g_i\ge2$ we shall also say that $S$ is isogenous to a *higher product*.

Where by the word "surface" the author means a complex algebraic variety of dimension $2$ (that is also a complex manifold) . In this case what is a finite unramified covering of $S$? In the article there are no definitions for coverings, but it seems that the author refers to a well known concept. In literature I have found only two concepts of "covering":

1. Topological coverings.
2. Coverings for compact Riemann Surfaces, i.e. coverings for smooth projective algebraic curves.

Comment: I think that more context is needed. The common generalization of a covering map is that of an etale morphism. That said, if someone called a surjective finite map a "cover" I wouldn't be shocked.

Comment: The context are complex algebraic surfaces. An article that I'm reading  cites a "cover" of a surface $X$.

Comment: In the (connected) Riemann surface setting one usually thinks of a cover as being a proper holomorphic map. These are always a (topological) covering off of a discrete set. I'm not sure though which is more apropos for your paper.

Comment: So  should I consider the complex manifold structure of my algebraic surface $X$?

Comment: I mean, I have no idea. I'm not reading your paper, you are. It all depends on context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context (i.e., for finite degree maps of compact connected complex manifolds) a *finite unramifield covering* is a locally biholomorphic map $p: S' \to S$. Equivalently, $p$ is a holomorphic map of two compact complex manifolds  which is also a topological covering. Equivalently, $p$ is a holomorphic fiber bundle with zero-dimensional (i.e., finite) fibers. The equivalences are not completely obvious. The two nontrivial ingredients you need are:

1. Every bijective holomorphic map between two open subsets of ${\mathbb C}^n$
   is actually biholomorphic, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497548/why-holomorphic-injection-on-cnmust-be-biholomorphic). This implies that a holomorphic topological covering is a holomorphic fiber bundle with zero-dimensional fiber.
2. [Ehresmann's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann's_theorem) which implies that a locally biholomorphic map between two connected compact complex manifolds is in fact a holomorphic fiber bundle with zero-dimensional fiber.