# Category of Riemann surface is balanced?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, category-theory, riemann-surfaces

Let $A$ and $B$ are Riemann surfaces.
$f:A→ B$ is morphism of Rieman surface, in other word, holomorhic function,
and supposed that $f$ is bijective.
Then, can we say that inverse of $f$ is also holomorphic?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The inverse of a bijective holomorphic function is also holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048204/the-inverse-of-a-bijective-holomorphic-function-is-also-holomorphic). For the record: The same applies for bijective holomorphic maps between higher-dimensional complex manifolds, inverses of such maps are again holomorphic. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497548/why-holomorphic-injection-on-cnmust-be-biholomorphic). But this is a more difficult result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Yes".

In suitable coordinates, a holomorphic mapping is locally represented by a convergent power series $z \mapsto w = a_{n}z^{n} + \cdots$ with $n \geq 1$ and $a_{n} \neq 0$. Such a mapping is locally bijective if and only if $n = 1$, if and only if it locally has a holomorphic inverse.

Comment: Can you please write more than one term? I assume that higher terms follow?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'm happy to edit if that will clarify, but yes, $a_nz^n$ denotes the lowest-order term of a convergent power series $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_kz^k$ at the origin, and the qualitative local behavior of a holomorphic function is governed by the first non-constant term. That seemed the crucial item to include (and potentially more clear than giving the whole series).